# Using regex to delete text based on first line of word docx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Hi I'm currently trying to format a word document whereby based on the word present in the first line a certain paragraph is kept. Example:

> We refer to above **(PST\Non-PST)** for your notice
>
> Paragraph 1
>
> Paragraph 2
>
> Paragraph 3

If the word **PST** is in the first line => keep paragraph 1 and delete paragraph 2 and 3.

If it's **Non-PST** keep paragraph 2 and delete 1 and 3

this is as far as i have managed to get

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace DataToPDF
{
    public class Replace_Text
    {
        public static void SearchAndReplace()
        {
            string document = @"C:\Users\kishlay02\Desktop\sample.docx";

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
            {
                string docText = null;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                if{

                    Regex regexText = new Regex("conclude");
                    docText = regexText.Matches("PST")


                }
                //Regex regexText1 = new Regex("conclude");
                //docText = regexText1.Replace(docText, "", 2);

                //Regex regexText2 = new Regex("conclude");
                //docText = regexText2.Replace(docText, "closer", 3);

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(docText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: I need help on coding this task. So far I've been only able to do a search for and replace function

Comment: Show us what you have tried. That's a good way to start getting serious answers :-)

Comment: added code and just to be clear the commented part is from the previous search and replace

Comment: I think the first issue with your code is that you need to isolate this first line. Btw, a `string` type also contains a `Contains` function. It might be easier to use in this case (eg.: `if (docText.Contains("PST"))`. Next; you'll need to isolate the paragraphs. so you are able to remove those. I don't have enough knowlage of this `WordprocessingDocument` library to help you any further.

Comment: @Kishen here is how it works in StackOverflow. You will post a question with the issue you are facing, solution you have tried, what is the desired result and what is your output. Also you should point to the exact line of code or syntax you have issue with. The community will just give you a **push** to resolve issue and **not code the entire feature for you**. More over most of them will not look at the entire code which you have posted and try to understand it.. you have to make it simpler.

Comment: Thank you both very much